# Recursive overview files PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, file, laravel, recursion, iterator

I have the recursive iterator overview, I get all the files but also all the directory's. I want only a overview of the files.
I have this code below:

```
<?php

$root = '/xampp/htdocs/systeembeheer/Storage/download/';

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
);

$paths = array($root);
foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
    if ($dir->isDir()) {
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use File (Illuminate\Support\Facades\File) facade:

```
    foreach (File::allFiles($root) as $file) {
        // $file->getFilename()
    }
```

API: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there are no Laravel specific ways to iterate directories in memory efficient manner.

Combination of PHP's `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` will work:

```php
$path = storage_path('some-path'); // example
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$iteratorIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator);

foreach ($iteratorIterator as $fileInfo) {
    var_dump($fileInfo->getPathname());
}
```

If you don't care about memory, like when you're sure your directory doesn't contain a lot of files, you can use `File::allFiles($path)` to return all file paths as array, like Winogronko mentioned.